# Custom string sorting

Tags: c++, string, qt, sorting

I am performing a sort on the following collection of strings using [QString::localeAwareCompare](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare-2):

**Search term used: "Mountain"**

Results:

- Goblin Mountaineer
- Madblind Mountain
- Magnetic Mountain
- Mountain
- Mountain Goat
- Mountain Stronghold
- Mountain Titan
- Mountain Valley
- Mountain Yeti
- Snow-Covered Mountain
- The Lady of the Mountain

The order is sorted lexically according to [QString::compare](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#compare-5).
Ultimately I would like the order to have the following rules:

1. Exact match at top
2. Exact match with preceding values sorted lexically.
3. Match contained in word sorted lexically

   - Mountain (1)
   - Mountain Goat (2)
   - Mountain Stronghold (2)
   - Mountain Titan (2)
   - Mountain Valley (2)
   - Mountain Yeti (2)
   - Goblin Mountaineer (3)
   - Madblind Mountain (3)
   - Magnetic Mountain (3)
   - Snow-Covered Mountain (3)
   - The Lady of the Mountain (3)

Does anyone know how this might be achieved? I am able to implement a custom sort of some kind.

EDIT:

Here is some janky code I have tried to get exact matches to the top, which works.

```
bool CardDatabaseDisplayModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const {

    QString leftString = sourceModel()->data(left).toString();
    QString rightString = sourceModel()->data(right).toString();

    if (leftString.compare(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0) {// exact match should be at top
        return true;
    }

    if (rightString.compare(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0) {// exact match should be at top
        return false;
    }

    return QString::localeAwareCompare(leftString, rightString) < 0;

}
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: @ArunA.S added something that I have tried as an experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way you could complete your current code. It tries to sort from the most special to the most general case: exact match, match-plus-stuff, everything else.

```
bool CardDatabaseDisplayModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, 
                               const QModelIndex &right) const {

    QString leftString = sourceModel()->data(left).toString();
    QString rightString = sourceModel()->data(right).toString();

    // The exact match (if any) should be at the top
    if (leftString.compare(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0)
        return true;
    if (rightString.compare(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0)
        return false;

    // We know that neither is the perfect match. 
    // But is either a match-plus-some-stuff ?
    bool isLeftType2 = leftString.startsWith(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    bool isRightType2 = rightString.startsWith(cardName, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    if (isLeftType2 && !isRightType2)
        return true;
    if (isRigthType2 && !isLeftType2)
        return false;

    // At this point we're sorting two matches of the same type
    // Either both are matches-plus-some-stuff or partial matches
    return QString::localeAwareCompare(leftString, rightString) < 0;
}
```

I assumed that something like "Mountaineer" alone would be type 2 and not type 3, you could add a `+" "` in the comparisons if you don't want that.